# Unable to solve this, updating arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am about to complete a text based java board game (Very basic). And I am stuck on this last thing -

Basically what happens is when a user has types 'roll' to roll the virtual die. Then depending on the results an array gets updated to change the location of 'o' (which makes it look like there counter has been moved). I have figured out how to make this for the first roll.

But what I cannot figure out is how to make the second roll and first roll add up (and so on with third and fourth roll).

(example -

Roll 1: Player rolls the die - gets a 3 - moves to 3rd position on the board (solved)

Roll 2: The game remembers that the last roll was a 3 - player rolls a 4 - updates the board and moves the counter to number 7)

Here is a snippet of the relevant code:

```
    public void play(String p1Name2, String p2Name2){

    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rn = new Random();
    String p1Roll = null,p2Roll;
    int[] p1r = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30};

    int b= 0,c= 0,d = 0,e = 0,g = 0;

    while(array1[10] != 'o'){
        c++;

            if(b==0) {
                int i =1;
                System.out.println("Player 1, type roll to roll the die. ");
                p1Roll = user_input.next();

                    if(p1Roll.equalsIgnoreCase("roll")){
                        p1r[c] = rn.nextInt(6);
                        p1r[c] += 1;
                        System.out.println("You rolled a: " + p1r[c]);


                        for(int f = 0; f< 10; f++ ){
                            if(array1[f] == 'o'){
                              array1[f] = 'x';
                              array1[p1r[c]] = 'o';
                              if(i ==1){
                                  this.board();
                                  i = 0;

                            }
                        }                       
                }
            }


            if(b==1) {      

            }

    }   
    }
}
```

and

```
    public void board(){


    System.out.println("           1  2  3  4  (5)  6  7  8  9  10  11");
    System.out.println("Player 1:  " + array1[0]+ "  " + array1[1] + "  " + array1[2]+ "  " + array1[3] + "   " + array1[4]+ "   " + array1[5] + "  " + array1[6]+ "  " + array1[7] + "  " + array1[8]+ "  " + array1[9] + "   " + array1[10]);
    System.out.println("Player 2:  " + array2[0]+ "  " + array2[1] + "  " + array2[2]+ "  " + array2[3] + "   " + array2[4]+ "   " + array2[5] + "  " + array2[6]+ "  " + array2[7] + "  " + array2[8]+ "  " + array2[9] + "   " + array2[10]);


}
```

Finally, here is the console output:

```
Player 1, type roll to roll the die. 
roll
You rolled a: 4
           1  2  3  4  (5)  6  7  8  9  10  11
Player 1:  x  x  x  x   o   x  x  x  x  x   x
Player 2:  o  x  x  x   x   x  x  x  x  x   x
Player 1, type roll to roll the die. 
roll
You rolled a: 4
           1  2  3  4  (5)  6  7  8  9  10  11
Player 1:  x  x  x  x   o   x  x  x  x  x   x
Player 2:  o  x  x  x   x   x  x  x  x  x   x
Player 1, type roll to roll the die. 
roll
You rolled a: 2
           1  2  3  4  (5)  6  7  8  9  10  11
Player 1:  x  x  o  x   x   x  x  x  x  x   x
Player 2:  o  x  x  x   x   x  x  x  x  x   x
Player 1, type roll to roll the die.
```

Comment: Is there a requirement to use array or are you free to use objects too? if you'd use objects it'd be a helluva lot easier and cleaner for you.

Comment: @engineer I tried, after one roll the counter ends up at the end.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets I could use objects, I am sorta new to java and unfamiliar with objects - could you suggest how I could do it with them?

Comment: gimme a moment to build up something @jordan

Answer (score 0):

You could change the code as follows:

```
public void play(String p1Name2, String p2Name2){

    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rn = new Random();
    String p1Roll = null,p2Roll;
    int[] p1r = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30};

    int b= 0,c= 0,d = 0,e = 0,g = 0;

    while(array1[10] != 'o'){
        c++;
        if(b==0) {
            int i =1;
            System.out.println("Player 1, type roll to roll the die. ");
            p1Roll = user_input.next();

                if(p1Roll.equalsIgnoreCase("roll")){
                    p1r[c] = rn.nextInt(6);
                    p1r[c] += 1;
                    System.out.println("You rolled a: " + p1r[c]);


                    for(int f = 0; f< 10; f++ ){
                        if(array1[f] == 'o'){
                          array1[f] = 'x';
                          /** Update Current Position **/
                          array1[p1r[f] + p1r[c]] = 'o';
                          if(i == 1){
                              this.board();
                              i = 0;
                          }
                          break;
                        }                       
                    }
                }
            }   
       }
   }
```

However, note that you're currently risking to get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException in `array[p1r[c]]`, as well as in the updated version. Hence, I would suggest you to address that, e.g.using moduled accesses `array[(p1r[c%p1r.length]%array.length)]`. It depends on the game behaviour you would like to have in such situations.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You asked me how it would look like in objects. it would look like this:

The group holds all the players.
The players have a board.
The board tracks each players location.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class Game
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Group group = new Group();
        group.createPlayer("Michael");
        group.createPlayer("Jeff");
        group.createPlayer("Fred"); 
        group.renderBoard();
        int round = 1;
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Game round "+round);
            round++;
            group.getInputs();
            group.renderBoard();
            if(group.isGameFinished()) {
                Player winner = group.getWinner();
                System.out.println("Player "+winner.getName() + " is the winner! Congratulations");
                break;
            }

        }
    }

}
class Group {
    private ArrayList<Player> group;
    public Group() {
        this.group =  new ArrayList<Player>();
    }
    public void createPlayer(String name) {
        this.group.add(new Player(name));
    }
    public void renderBoard() {
        Iterator<Player> it = this.group.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Player current = it.next();
            current.renderBoard();
        }
    }
    public void getInputs() {
        Iterator<Player> it = this.group.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Player currentMove = it.next();
            currentMove.getDiceRoll();
        }
    }
    public boolean isGameFinished() {
        Iterator<Player> it = this.group.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Player currentMove = it.next();
            if(currentMove.isFinished()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public Player getWinner() {
        Iterator<Player> it = this.group.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Player currentMove = it.next();
            if(currentMove.isFinished()) {
                return currentMove;
            }
        }
        return new Player("Nobody");
    }
}
class Player {
        private Scanner user_input;
        private Random rn;
        private String name;
        private Board board;
        public Player(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            this.user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
            this.rn = new Random();
            this.board = new Board(11);
        }
        public void getDiceRoll() {
            System.out.println("Player "+this.name+", type roll to roll the die. ");
            String input = user_input.next();
            if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("roll")) {
                int dieRoll = rn.nextInt(6);
                System.out.println("You rolled a "+dieRoll+"!");
                this.board.updateLocation(dieRoll);
            }
        }
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
        public boolean isFinished() {
            return this.board.isFinished();
        }
        public void renderBoard() {
            System.out.println(this.name +" > "+this.board.renderBoard());
        }
    }
    class Board {
        private int size;
        private int location;
        public Board(int size) {
             this.size = size;
             this.location = size;
        }
        public void reset() {
            this.location = this.size;
        }
        public boolean isFinished() {
            return this.location <= 0;
        }
        public void updateLocation(int amount) {
            this.location -= amount;
            if(this.location < 0) {
                this.location = 0;
            }
        }
        public String renderBoard() {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for(int c=0;c<=this.size;c++) {
                if(c == this.location) {
                    builder.append('o');
                }
                else {
                    builder.append('x');
                }
                builder.append(' ');
            }
            return builder.toString();
        }
    }
```